# nginx root path issues for react

Tags: reactjs, nginx, amazon-ec2, server

I am having issues running my react app on nginx which i am running on AWS EC2 instance.
My files paths for index.html is in build:

```
`-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1353 Sep 23 08:52 asset-manifest.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 3870 Sep 23 08:52 favicon.ico
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 3212 Sep 23 08:52 index.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 5347 Sep 23 08:52 logo192.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 9664 Sep 23 08:52 logo512.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  492 Sep 23 08:52 manifest.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1231 Sep 23 08:52 precache-manifest.7e468f7af076de91adb94c7c9a531eff.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   67 Sep 23 08:52 robots.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1039 Sep 23 08:52 service-worker.js
drwxrwxr-x 5 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Sep 23 08:52 static
ubuntu:~/Desktop/Restaurant_App/front-end/build$ pwd
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Restaurant_App/front-end/build `
```

I added react.conf file in the following way :

```
`server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /home/ubantu/Desktop/Restaurant-App/front-end/build;
    location / {
    try_files $uri /home/ubantu/Desktop/app-deploy/public/index.html;
    }
}`
```

This is not working, it is not displaying the actual page and shoing standard nginx page. I have spent 4 days on this and no video or chatgpt is helping in this so far.

I have changed the server multiple time but it does not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled the path (ubantu vs ubuntu):

Change:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /home/ubantu/Desktop/Restaurant-App/front-end/build;
    location / {
    try_files $uri /home/ubantu/Desktop/app-deploy/public/index.html;
    }
}
```

To:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /home/ubuntu/Desktop/Restaurant-App/front-end/build;
    location / {
    try_files $uri /home/ubuntu/Desktop/app-deploy/public/index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. Could it be possible to get information how to write code for react.conf file ?

Comment: Ok, let's look at this more closely.  Where exactly are your react build files? From the path, "/home/ubuntu/Desktop", it looks like it's on a desktop and not the AWS server.
After you run 'npm run build', you need to copy everything under the 'build' folder it creates TO the server 'html' folder.  Is that what you are doing?

Comment: ok so this is the path: /home/ubuntu/Desktop/Restaurant-App/front-end .
the front-end is the react app with reacts standard files when create the app. You go further in u will find build, public, etc. files. there is similar folder by the name back-end which contains API for the app making it dynamic app, with that out of way.

Ok so initially i was watching a tutorial it showed me to 'npm run build' and copy files to folder called app-deploy. app deploy path is: /home/ubuntu/Desktop/app-deploy. and from there it showed writing server script and saving it in react.conf for nginx

Comment: the current code for server shared here is altered in me trying to run it with diffrenet paths but unsucessful. It does show default index page of nginx but me messing with it now just makes it show 404, or server not responding page

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /home/ubuntu/Desktop/Restaurant_App/front-end/build;
    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. Thanks thuogh

Comment: @usmanmuhammad what is the error response?

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to solve the problem by moving a copy of build file to /var/www/html/.

And made changes to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default to redirect it the file to the build folder:

```
server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            listen [::]:80 default_server;
            root /var/www/html/build;
            index index.html index.htm;
            server_name _;        
            location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            }
}
```